Composed Taylor series expansions with $n$ th exponentiation operator
Assume that we can expanse the coordinates difference between two point $\mathbf x-\mathbf y$ by $$x_i - y_i = \rho A_i(\theta) + \rho^2 B_i(\theta) + O(\rho^3). \tag{E1}
$$
Where $A_i(\theta)$ and $B_i(\theta)$ are just simple trigonometric functions of $\theta$.
It is then convenient to define
$$ A(\theta) = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{3} [A_k(\theta)]^2 \right)^{1/2} > 0, $$
$$B(\theta) = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{3} [B_k(\theta)]^2 \right)^{1/2} \geq 0$$
In an article, they say :

According to the previous result (E1), the Taylor series expansions for the powers of $r = |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|$ are given by (repeated indices imply summation)
$$ r^n = \rho^n A^n \left( 1 + n \rho \frac{A_k B_k}{A^2} \right) + O(\rho^{n+2}), \quad n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots $$

I want to have an expansion of $r^n$ as indicated in this excerpt. But I have some difficulties to express it as it is in the article.
NB : $$r^n=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3}(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{n/2}.$$
If you want to see the full article, Appendix C : https://doi.org/10.1115/1.2893766.
Thanks for any help.

Alright, I found out where the difficulty came from: it comes from the fact that the Taylor expansion is made with the $\mathcal O$ notation and not with the classical $\mathcal o$ one. For example, for sinus Taylor expansion, we have
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal o}(x^5).$$
But we can also write
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^7)$$
because the next term can be written as
$$\frac{x^7}{5040}+\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal o}(x^7)=\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^7).$$
The same idea holds for my problem. We have to truncate the series expansion to an order lower than the "bounded" term around $0$, which is the best that we can do. If we write $\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^5)$ (which is also true bay the way because $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^7)\in\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal o}(x^5)\in\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^5)$ - but the opposite inclusion is false), we are losing some information and the expansion is not optimal!
For my problem, we can easily show (only using $y_i-x_i=\rho A_i(\theta)+\rho^2B_i(\theta)+\underset{\rho\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(\rho^3)$ and some basic operations on $\underset{\rho\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}$ like multiplication, multiplication by a constant, addition etc...) that
\begin{align*}
r^2=\sum_{i=1}^{3}(y_i-x_i)^2 & =\rho^2\left\{A^2(\theta)+2\rho\sum_{i=1}^{3}A_i(\theta)B_i(\theta)\right\}+\underset{\rho\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(\rho^4)\\
& = \rho^2A^2(\theta)\left\{1+2\rho\sum_{i=1}^{3}A_i(\theta)B_i(\theta)/A^2(\theta)+\underset{\rho\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(\rho^2)\right\}.
\end{align*}
We then define $u=2\rho\sum_{i=1}^{3}A_i(\theta)B_i(\theta)/A^2(\theta)+\underset{\rho\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(\rho^2)$ and we use
$$(1+u)^\alpha=1+\alpha u+\underset{u\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(u^2)$$ (going to the first power of $u$ and bounded by its second power, as explained before) to develop $r^n=(r^2)^{n/2}.$
NB : as $u$ has a linear term in $\rho$, the asymptotic behavior around $0$ of $u$ is the same as $\rho$ : $\underset{u\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(u^2)\in \underset{\rho\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(\rho^2)$.
NB: I write the $\in$ symbol to compare some $\mathcal O$ and $\mathcal o$ terms with each other because if I write "$=$", it's ambiguous because the equality must be valid only in one sense, and not the other, so $\in$ is more appropriated. For example $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^7)\in\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^5)$ but $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^5)\notin\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\mathcal O}(x^7)$.
